# How can I create this figure?

Tags: html, css, layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFaXr.png)

I faced a problem in my layout. Can anyone help me make this shape using html / css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, with the following HTML:

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #F0AC23;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #F0AC23;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor picture quality